# Is polynomial interpolation with RKHS in some way more advantageous than simple Lagrange interpolation?

Tags: kernel-smoothing, polynomial, interpolation

The reproducing kernel Hilbert space associated with the polynomial kernel $K(x,z)=(1+xz)^{d-1}$ (or other similar polynomials) can be used to interpolate a continuous function $f$ at by its value at points $\{x_i\}.$ When we have $d$ such points, the interpolation is the same as interpolating with Lagrange's formula. For other situations, the RHKS is a generalisation of Lagrange's method of interpolation.

We know some easy results (by applying Taylor theorem) about the error of interpolating with Lagrange's formula. I am wondering - are there any other similar results with the RKHS version of interpolation? In particular,

1. When should we choose $d$ to be larger than the number of data points, to reduce error?
2. How can we prove a theorem to explain such theoretical advantage?

Any reference would be really helpful.